# Firestore structured query search by document id

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, zapier

I'm trying to query a firestore collection by document id but not using firestore CLI but rather a structured query (because I'm using Zapier to automate some workflows). Is there a way to search by documented as the field? So far I've tried the below code and variations where I replace **name** with "documentId()", "documentId" and nothing seems to work. When I use **name** I get the following error:

> "error":
> "code": 400,
> "message": "**key** filter value must be a Key",
> "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"

```
"where": {
    "fieldFilter": {
        "field": {
            "fieldPath": "__name__"
        },
        "op": "EQUAL",
        "value": {
            "stringValue": "THE ID I WANT TO LOOK FOR"
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Hi @ByAdham, your question is a bit confusing. Do you want to get a specific document using a document ID or do you want to get a document which has a specific `value` of a field? Your code is not the same as you stated on your question.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get a document by id using `__name__`, change the value type to `referenceValue` and provide the full path to the document instead of just the id for the query.

```
"where": {
  "fieldFilter": {
    "field": {
      "fieldPath": "__name__"
    },
    "op": "EQUAL",
    "value": {
      "referenceValue": "projects/project_id/databases/database_id/documents/your_collection/doc_id"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to get a specific document using a document id. You may want to refer to the code below:

```
axios.get(`https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<Project-ID>/databases/(default)/documents/<Collection-Name>/<Document-ID>`)
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

The code above will get a specific document that you want. If you want to get a document ID with a specific value of its field, then this line here: `"fieldPath": "__name__"` should be a `fieldName` not a document id. `"fieldPath": "<FieldName>"`. and also, make sure the method you're using is `POST`. See code sample below for reference:

```
axios.post(`https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<Project-ID>/databases/(default)/documents:runQuery`,
{
  "structuredQuery": {
      "from": [{
          "collectionId": "<Collection-Name>"
      }],
      "where": {
          "fieldFilter": {
              "field": {
                  "fieldPath": "<FieldName>"
              },
              "op": "EQUAL",
              "value": {
                  stringValue: "<FieldValue>"
              }
          }
      }
  }
}).then(res => { 
  console.log(res) 
})
.catch(error => { 
  console.log(error) 
})
```

All the codes above are for reference only which I used `axios` for fetching the data from Firestore.

For more information, checkout this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api).